# error regarding ffmpeg while using python to access a wav file

Tags: python-2.7

When I used python audio segment to open a .wav file and divide it into many .wav files i am getting this error

> "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pydub\utils.py:165: RuntimeWarning: Couldn't find
>   ffmpeg or avconv - defaulting to ffmpeg, but may not work
>
> warn("Couldn't find ffmpeg or avconv - defaulting to ffmpeg, but may not work"
>   , RuntimeWarning)"

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you don't have [ffmpeg](https://www.ffmpeg.org), which is listed in the [dependencies](https://github.com/jiaaro/pydub#dependencies) section of the Pydub GitHub. However, it is only required if you wish to load or save non-WAV files.

This message is just a warning, if you're using Pydub solely for WAV files, it is safe to simply ignore it.